# show paperclip ( images) which stores in another app, current app already connect with the external database,Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, image, paperclip, external

I have a new app, and I want share the common part with another ror app.

For example, I have a MVC named `showcase` for showing images in the previous app, I want have the same one in my new app too.

Now I have connect my new app with the previous app's database, create a model with same name"showcase", and could get its columns like `image_file_name; image_content_type;; image_file_size`..  but in the view page for showcase in the new app, it can not recognize `image`which is  paperclip type attribute.

Can anyone tell me how can I use the images from the previous app?

Thanks a lot!

**update:**

```
class Showcase < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://localhost:3000"
end
```

controller:

```
class ShowcasesController < ApplicationController
   def index
    @showcases = Showcase.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @showcases }
      format.xml { render :xml => @showcases }
    end
  end

  def show
    @showcase = Showcase.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @showcase }
      format.xml { render :xml => @showcases }
    end
  end
end
```

view:

```
<%= image_tag @showcase.image.url %
```

the error:
undefined method"image" for  #

how could my view recognize image?

by the way in the original app, it didn't render xml, so I manually append render xml is that ok?

```
format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @showcase }
      format.xml { render :xml => @showcases }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a proper restful API to access the showcase resource in your first app(app1), then you can use the showcase model from the other ROR app(app2) ActiveResource. ActiveResource abstracts the communication between the two applications and it looks as though the model belonged to the same application.

If the restful url for showcase model in app1 is www.app1.com/showcases, then in the app2, all you have to do is create a model named showcase like below.

```
class ShowCase < ActiveResource:Base
 self.site="www.app1.com" 
end
```

Check out rails cast episode http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics for more details.

Comment: thank you it is a new idea for me, I have seen the episode, and tried but failed. I have update my question above! thanks!